# Search only in title and only all words

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I feel really stupid asking this, but NuGet just annoyed the hell out of me...

I tried to find the "ASP.NET Web API Help Page" package. So I entered that in the search box. But the results look like NuGet returns anything that matches at least one of my words - even if that match is in the description.
How to change the search so it returns only relevant matches - similar to google?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it supports phrases for searching at the moment. I'd suggest you file an issue at http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I filed an issue: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2641